# Javascript variable declaration syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-declaration

I'm taking charge of a javascript webapp. It's very complex, and I'm having some trouble with syntax:

```
getThemeBaseUrl = function() {
  var customConfigPath = "./customer-configuration";                    
  if (parseQueryString().CustomConfigPath) {                           
    customConfigPath = parseQueryString().CustomConfigPath;
  }
  var clientId = parseQueryString().ClientId; 

  return customConfigPath + "/themes/" + clientId;
};

parseQueryString = function() {
  var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1), re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
  while ( m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }
  return result;
};
```

in particular `parseQueryString().CustomConfigPath` and the `var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1), re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;`

The first seems to be a sort of property access by the parseQueryString function.

The second seems an array declaration, but without the Array() constructor. Also, the `m` value is recalled without the presumed array result in the while cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at:

```
parseQueryString().CustomConfigPath
```

you can say that `parseQueryString()` is expected to return an object with `CustomConfigPath` property.

And from this:

```
var result = {};
```

you see that `result` is indeed an object (`{}` is an empty object literal). **It is not an array.** Later, in a loop, there is:

```
result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
```

so we're assigning properties to the `result` object. One of this properties will be (as we can expect) a `CustomConfigPath`. This will be taken from the query string - we'll use regular expression to do this: `re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g`. So address of the webpage on which this code is executed looks like: `http://example.com/something?SomeKey=value&CustomConfigPath=something`.

General syntax for assigning properties to an object is:

```
result[key] = value;
// key   -> decodeURIComponent(m[1]) 
// value -> decodeURIComponent(m[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseQueryString().CustomConfigPath` calls the `parseQueryString` function, which returns an object. Then it accesses the `CustomConfigPath` property of that object. A common idiom for the first 4 lines of the function is:

```
var customConfigPath = parseQueryString().CustomConfigPath || "/.customer-configuration";
```

`var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1), re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m` is a declaration of 4 different variables, not an array:

- `result` is an empty object
- `queryString` is the query string from the current URL, with the `?` removed.
- `re` is a regular expression
- `m` is a variable that isn't initialized, it will be assigned later in the `while` loop.